# Sqlite version for Firefox 40.0

Tags: python, firefox, cookies, sqlite

I am trying to access cookies.sqlite of a firefox profile using embedded sqlite3 in python.

```
>>> import sqlite3
>>> conn = sqlite3.connect(COOKIES_FILEPATH)
```

*COOKIES_FILEPATH is replaced with actual file path.

On running the above script, I am facing the following error.

```
 sqlite3.OperationalError: unable to open database file
```

Is it because Firefox 40.0 uses an older version of Sqlite or there are some restrictions on using cookies.sqlite from Firefox Profile.

I recursively gave the directory holding the profile all the permission (777).

Can someone please elaborate why is this happening?

Comment: So how certain are you that `COOKIES_FILEPATH` is the right file path?

Comment: I copied the contents of the profile folder to a folder names Profile at Desktop. I am using the path "~/Desktop/Profile/cookies.sqlite".

Comment: Python does not expand `~` in paths. Use `os.path.expanduser()` to explicitly expand it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQLite has an excellent track record of maintaining backwards compatibility, and the error message would reflect it if there was an issue with the database file.

The error indicates that you have your path wrong. Make sure you have an absolute path to the file that you have verified to exist. You could use Python to do the latter:

```
os.isfile(COOKIES_FILEPATH)
```

Use the [`os.path` module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html) to make your path absolute if it is relative or contains environment variables ([`os.path.expandvars()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#os.path.expandvars)) or the `~` reference ([`os.path.expanduser()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#os.path.expanduser)); your shell may expand these but Python does not unless explicitly told to.